# Switching ctrl and cmd on MacOs

Tags: shortcut, osx

Is there a way to switch the control and cmd keys while working with blender? The short-cuts bacome kind of inconvenient, because I am used to work on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it in the user preferences in the left corner by clicking on *File* then *User Preferences*. From the window that opens choose the *Input* tab and then change the keyboard shortcut for the desired key. Then you are done.

You can get the [pdf for keyboard shortcuts](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/free-blender-keyboard-shortcut-pdf). It's a simple keyboard shortcut PDF and may help you in future.

Comment: if you got problems you can ask.